# How do I get the correct path to a JSON file from a URL?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

[image]

How do I get the "request url" part of the get request?

The number part is time in milliseconds but the part before the ".dat" in the URL changes for every game so I need a way to get the whole URL, using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup4`.
link to page https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/1-fc-koln-holstein-kiel-0IRBLw8b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an interesting challenge so I decided to have a look.

You can construct the url from various parts of the initial response, with the inclusion of a tab mapping for football (shown in dictionary). It may be possibly to derive the mappings for the dictionary dynamically from the `onmousedown` arguments and the associated `uid` function. I started looking into it and may carry on time permits. Hardcoding for football, for full/1st half/2nd half tabs, seems to be ok for now.

```
import requests
import re, urllib, time

time_lkup = {
    'full_time':'1-2',
    'first_half':'1-3',
    'second_half':'1-4'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0',
                 'referer': 'https://www.oddsportal.com'}
    r = s.get('https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/1-fc-koln-holstein-kiel-0IRBLw8b/')
    version_id = re.search(r'"versionId":(\d+)', r.text).group(1)
    sport_id = re.search(r'"sportId":(\d+)', r.text).group(1)
    xeid = re.search(r'"id":"(.*?)"', r.text).group(1)
    xhash = urllib.parse.unquote(re.search(r'"xhash":"(.*?)"', r.text).group(1))
    unix = int(time.time())
    url = f'https://fb.oddsportal.com/feed/match/{version_id}-{sport_id}-{xeid}-{time_lkup["full_time"]}-{xhash}.dat?_={unix}'
    print(url)
    r = s.get(url)
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: yoo thank you so much. would have never figured that out myself !